# spring CONTROLLER cannot be included

Tags: spring

```
package com.mybatis.control;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller 

public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping
    public String test() {
        return("test");
    }
}
```

At line 3 I need to add a `@Controller` annotation, but I am unable to add. Rather than I am getting a stereotype.

Answer (score 0):

yes its correct

```
@Component, @Service, @Controller, @Repository
```

are available in

```
org.springframework.stereotype
```

package.

Comment: will it work in the same way that a normal @controller annotation works ???

Comment: yes, thats the only correct annotation which you should add here. Though there is one more @RestController( available in org.springframework.web.bind.annotation) which is used for restful services

Comment: your class name is also Controller. so when you are adding @Controller annotation it is coming along with the package name. So thats okay. But i suggest you to change your Class name to like StudentController or AdminController

Comment: thank you it worked #changed the class name @Navneet Singh